# Testing for Nested divs using Vue Test Utils

Tags: javascript, vue.js

So I have this shallowMounted vue component:

```
<div class="card p-relative">
  <div class="card-header">
    <div class="card-title h4">
      a cute title
      <!---->
      <!---->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!---->
  <div class="card-body">
    <h3 class="circle" style="background-color: rgb(237, 15, 59);"></h3>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h6 class="card-body">Value: 35</h6>
  </div>
</div>
```

I am doing a shallowMount:

```
const wrapper = shallowMount(Component, { proposData: { 'shape': 'circle'}})
```

Later trying to find all the classes, so I can somehow find the class circle. But what I got:

```
const results = wrapper.classes()
console.log(results) // ['card', 'p-relative']
```

How to find the h3 or class 'circle' :/

Completely Noob to frontend. Please forgive for using wrong vocabulary.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/selectors.html to access direct descendants.

I did the following:

```
    const shape = wrapper.find('.card-body > h3')
    console.log(shape.classes()) //['circle']
```

Comment: I am having an issue where I am unable to access a child selector… the parent returns a wrapper object but the child returns undefined…do you know why this is? Here is a link to an SO question I posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71150348/unable-to-use-vue-test-utils-v1-find-method-for-nested-dom-elements?noredirect=1#comment125773084_71150348